# Making attribute features pop up in a static location

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am writing an ArcGIS application that has a 20% left pane div and an 80% map div. The left pane div has four tabs: one for layers, one for search, one for what I want to display information, and one for what will eventually become a geoenrichment display.

I have no problem making the popup happen. Everything displays correctly and it looks fine. However, I want the popup to only populate into the left pane.

I've seen the ESRI published tutorial and although it is what I need to do, I'm having trouble making it work.

Comment: I don't think the geoenrichment tag is required here. The contents of the 4th panel are irrelevant - the real question is how to push the popup's content to the 3rd panel

Answer (score 1):

See the Esri sample [Popup content in side panel](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/popup_sidepanel.html) where the following function pushes the contents of the infoWindow to the div with ID "leftPane":

```
function displayPopupContent(feature){
  if(feature){
    var content = feature.getContent();
    registry.byId("leftPane").set("content", content);
  }
}
```

Add a div with an ID to your left-hand pane, and use a similar logic to populate it with the infoWindow's contents.